# Knowing if a member has viewed a thread

Tags: php, notifications

I'm working with a standard post/comments system where one member writes a post and other members may comment. When a member comments they can choose to receive notifications about any new comments - fairly standard stuff.

I then send out emails to the relevant members when new comments are submitted. What I'd like to make sure of is that I'm sending those notifications to the members who **have not viewed** the comments since the last comment was submitted.

If the member is logged in, then that's easy. But what about if the member hasn't logged in? I thought about adding the member's id and some sort of secret key in to the link that they receive in the email thats sent to them - these two methods combined I think would cover more than 95% of cases - but I'm curious to know if anyone uses any really clever way of ensuring that they always capture the fact that the member has viewed a post and it's comments - even if they're not logged in? I can't see how it's possible to cover all scenarios.

Are there any common patterns for this sort of problem?

For reference, I have a batch job which runs every 5 mins to send out the notification emails.

Thanks,

James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is keep a 'seen' list tied to the user. If this user isn't logged in you can try identifying the user with as said a cookie. But if the user doesn't identify himself from a friend's computer and then moves to his own computer there is no way for you make the connection. In fact, your user can use two different browsers, one logged in and one not. You cannot safely assume that this is the same person.

One would explain this 5% problem in a FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already considered creating a cookie?

```
viewerID={encode($someUniqueID)}
```

Comment: Yes - I was planning on leaving a cookie with which I could identify them, even after they've logged out. But am I right in thinking that there's absolutely no way of identifying them if they are viewing from say their friend's PC, or their mobile etc....i.e. devices/browsers which won't have the cookie?

Comment: Nope. There's nothing that identifies them when they aren't at their 'original position' anymore, they *need* to identify themselves first.